# Refer to a loaded pgfplotstable via csname

Tags: pgfplotstable, csname

I would like to be able to use `\csname` to manipulate a table previously assigned to a macro via `\pgfplotstableread`. Attempting to use the macro indirectly, however, fails to compile. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  a  b
  1  4
  2  5
  3  6
}{\testTable}

% OK
%\pgfplotstabletypeset{\testTable}

% Fails to compile
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\csname testTable\endcsname}

\end{document}
```

When attempting to compile the version of the `\pgfplotstabletypeset` command that uses `\csname`, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\testTable ->\pgfpl@@ 
                      {a}\pgfpl@@ {b}
l.18 ...stabletypeset{\csname testTable\endcsname}
```

Is it possible to refer to a loaded pgfplotstable in this way? I also tried replacing the command involving `\csname` with

```
\newcommand{\myTable}{\testTable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\myTable}
```

only to obtain the same sort of error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the csname before calling `\pgfplotstabletypeset`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  a  b
  1  4
  2  5
  3  6
}{\testTable}

% OK
%\pgfplotstabletypeset{\testTable}

% Fails to compile
\expandafter\pgfplotstabletypeset\expandafter{\csname testTable\endcsname}

\end{document}
```