# Using \csname to iterate over loaded pgfplots tables with \addplot

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, csname

I'm attempting to create a pgfplots group plot in which each curve is made from a pre-loaded pgfplots table in an automated way. The intended application is for a complicated drawing involving many tables. The MWE below illustrates the issue. With suitable use of `\expandafter` (thanks to the answer to this previous question: [Refer to a loaded pgfplotstable via csname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603645/61460)), I can get a loop over multiple tables to work with `\pgfplotstabletypeset`. A similar loop which tries to plot both datasets fails to compile. I'd like to be able to use the unaltered `\addplot` syntax in such a loop. There may be a way of wrapping the invocation of `\addplot` in a `\newcommand` which could get the `\expandafter` trick to work, but defining a new macro for every plot I'd like to make will be inconvenient and potentially fragile. Ideally, I'd like to be able to (1) use the name passed to `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` to call `\addplot` multiple times with different options, and (2) if possible, switch to using a numerical list, e.g., `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,5}`, to implement the plotting loop.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  a  b
  1  4
  2  5
  3  6
}{\testTableOne}

\pgfplotstableread{
  a  b
  1  2
  2  3
  3  4
}{\testTableTwo}

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{One,Two}{%
  \expandafter\pgfplotstabletypeset\expandafter{\csname testTable#1\endcsname}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style = {group size = 1 by 2}]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{One,Two}{
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot table[ x = a, y = b ]
    % This fails to compile
    {\csname testTable#1\endcsname};
    % This works, but doesn't vary the plot
    %{\testTableOne};
}
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to change syntax, so controlling expansion is easier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addplotnamedtable}{oO{}m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {% the call is like \addplot table[...}{...}
    \use:e { \exp_not:n { \addplot table~[#2] } { \exp_not:c { #3 } } }
   }
   {% the call is like \addplot [...] table [...] {...}
    \use:e { \exp_not:n { \addplot [#1]~table~[#2] } { \exp_not:c { #3 } } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  a  b
  1  4
  2  5
  3  6
}{\testTableOne}

\pgfplotstableread{
  a  b
  1  2
  2  3
  3  4
}{\testTableTwo}

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{One,Two}{%
  \expandafter\pgfplotstabletypeset\expandafter{\csname testTable#1\endcsname}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style = {group size = 1 by 2}]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{One,Two}{
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplotnamedtable [sharp plot, mark=*, mark options={fill=green}][x = a, y = b ] {testTable#1};
}
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works nicely for the case shown above, but it runs into problems when {} characters are used in the options that appear before the table name. For instance, `\addplotnamed[sharp plot, mark=*, mark options={fill=green}] table[ x = a, y = b ] {testTable#1};` currently fails to compile.

Comment: @StevenGardiner Can there be braces also in the `[...]` part after `table`?

Comment: Yes, I have some use cases in which this occurs. `table` can take the `y expr` option which needs braces for calling `\thisrow{}`, etc.

Comment: @StevenGardiner I changed the implementation. Maybe it would be possible to keep the infix `table` syntax, but…

Answer (score 0):

A solution that resolves item (1) but not item (2) in the question above is to create a special version of `\pgfplotstablecopy`. This version takes a first argument that names a loaded table macro without the leading `\` character. A caveat is that using `\thisrow{}` within the options passed to `table` does not seem to work with the copied table (but does with the original).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  a  b
  1  4
  2  5
  3  6
}{\testTableOne}

\pgfplotstableread{
  a  b
  1  2
  2  3
  3  4
}{\testTableTwo}

% Define the \backslashchar macro to be a \ character with a normal catcode.
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7372/61460 for an explanation. We will
% use this character below to trick pgfplotstable into allowing us to copying
% from a loaded table without using a leading \ in the name.
\begingroup\lccode`!=`\\\lowercase{\endgroup\def\backslashchar{!}}

% Make a special version of the macro \pgfplotstablecopy. This version copies
% from a loaded table specified as the first argument without a leading \.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Specialpgfplotstablecopy}[2]{%
  \edef#2{\expandafter\noexpand\csname #1\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\pgfplotstable@loc@TMPa%
    \csname\backslashchar\string#1@@table@name\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname\string#2@@table@name\endcsname=\pgfplotstable@loc@TMPa
  \expandafter\edef\csname\string#2@@table@scanline\endcsname{\csname\backslashchar\string#1@@table@scanline\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\pgfplotslistforeachungrouped\csname#1\endcsname\as\pgfplotstable@loc@TMPa{%
    \def\pgfplotstable@loc@TMPb{%
      \expandafter\let\csname\string#2@\pgfplotstable@loc@TMPa\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\pgfplotstable@loc@TMPb\csname\backslashchar\string#1@\pgfplotstable@loc@TMPa\endcsname
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style = {group size = 1 by 2}]

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{One,Two}{
      \nextgroupplot
      \Specialpgfplotstablecopy{testTable#1}{\tempTable};
      \addplot[sharp plot, mark=*, mark options={fill=green}]
        table[ x = a, y = b ] {\tempTable};
      % Breaks due to the \thisrow{} expression.
      % It works for the original table.
      %\addplot[sharp plot, mark=*, mark options={fill=green}]
      %  table[ x = a, y expr = \thisrow{b} ] {\tempTable};
    }

  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```